# Using a Typedef Struct inside a Typedef Struct linked list C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, typedef

I'm having trouble understanding why i get this error :

```
error : expected identifier before '(' token
```

The error appears each time i wanna fill the data of the Trans struct inside the Etat struct

Here's the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Transition Transition;
struct Transition
{
    char symb[5];
    int  nvEtat[5];
};

typedef struct Etat Etat;
struct Etat
{
    int     etat;
    Transition trans;
    int     estFinal; /* Etat final ou non */
    Etat    *suivant;
};

Etat *tete=NULL;
Etat *p;
/*_______________________________________________________________
*/
void Ajouter(void){
    int i,j,k;
    Etat *nouveau;

    j=0;
    while(j=0)
    {

        nouveau = calloc(1,sizeof (struct Etat));
        if(nouveau!=NULL){

            printf("\nNumero de l'etat : ");
            scanf("%d",&(nouveau->etat));

            i=0;
            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
             nouveau->(trans->symb[i]) = 'a' ; /*initialize all symbols to a*/
            }

            i=0;
            while(k==0 && i<5)
            {
             printf("Avec quel symbole vers le nouvel etat : ");
             scanf(" %c",&(nouveau->(trans->symb[i])));

             printf("Vers quel etat : ");
             scanf("%d",&(nouveau->(trans->nvEtat[i])));

             printf("Y a t-il encore des transition depuis cet etat ? (0 pour oui ) ");
             scanf("%d",&k);
             i++;
            }

            printf("\nEst ce que c'est un etat final ? ( 0 final , 1 non )");
            scanf("%d",&(nouveau->estFinal));

            if(tete==NULL){
                tete=nouveau;
            }else{
                p = tete;
                while(p->suivant !=NULL){
                    p=p->suivant;
                }
                p->suivant = nouveau;
            }

            printf("\nVoulez vous ajouter une autre transition? (0 pour ajouter) ");
            scanf("%d",&j);

        }else{
            perror("\nPas assez de memoire ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
/*_______________________________________________________________
*/
/*_______________________________________________________________
*/
int main(void){
    Ajouter();
    Afficher();
    return 0;
}
```

If you can give me a way to use the type of struct such as " Transition " inside another struct that'd be very helpful !

Thank you for your help.

PS: I will try to translate the printfs in english if it can help understand the code

Comment: I think you're just misinterpreting the compiler error. Had to change several things to be able to compile. nouveau->(trans->symb[i]) has parenthesis it shouldn't have and the trans member is not a pointer. It should be nouveau->trans.symb[i]. My visual studio also complained about k not being initialized before use. Should probably do that too.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will try to change and see the result